# Active Presenter, Muting Single Layer

Tags: video-editor, editing, audio

I'm using active presenter, and I'm trying to mute the audio on an mp4 file I imported, while keeping the mp3 file on another layer playing. But it's seeming that whenever I click properties on the item and go to mute the sound of the video file, it mutes every library file. Including the Mp3 I imported on another layer. And if I turn it back on in the MP3's properties, despite it listing the correct name of the item, it turns it back on for the MP4 file. How can I mute one file while another keeps playing? There's no separate layers for audio/video when I imported the Mp4, otherwise I'd have just deleted it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have changed the system playback volume by clicking the sound icon in the **Properties** pane.

You can change the volume of (and mute) any layer or range by using the **Adjust Volume** tool in **Timeline** as shown in below image.

[image]